# Is it possible to obtain warnings from javadoc when something missed in javadoc-comments?

Tags: java, documentation, javadoc

Accidentally I may forget to describe some parameters or exception throwing (or something else) when documenting methods or classes, etc.

Is it possible to run javadoc in such a way that it warns me about missing documentation items?

(I use ant script for generating documentation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/)! It has awesome Ant integration and supports 100s of other important checks to your source code too.

The [JavadocType checker](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html) is what you'll need though.

Answer (score 8):

I do not know of any javadoc option that will issue a warning about non-documented items.

However, if You happen to use Eclipse, take a look at the settings in

Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Javadoc

There, You can tell Eclipse to issue warnings on undocumented items.

Comment: Same answer in same time ;) Eclipse is mother for java development... ;)

Comment: Thanks, this is useful, but not exactly what I need. I would like to have some command line tool, if javadoc not allows to do what I need.

Answer (score 2):

We used [Doc Check Doclet](http://java.sun.com/j2se/javadoc/doccheck/) for an earlier project. It can be integrated with the build and generates useful reports that tell you which code has poor documentation.

NOTE: The tool is beta and no longer supported by Sun.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, in Eclipse you have incorporate check for everything what you define, so it is possible to put this missing into "warnings" and than you will e able to see where you make mistakes.